# Undesired error in length() when running a glmer() model in R

Tags: r, glm, lme4

My dataset looks like this:

```
> head(GLM_df)
   hour Feeding Foraging Standing ID    Area     Feeding_Foraging
1     0  0.119     0.789   0.0339 41361 Seronera            0.908
2     1  0.0920    0.819   0.0339 41361 Seronera            0.911
3     2  0.0847    0.824   0.0678 41361 Seronera            0.909
4     3  0.233     0.632   0.132  41361 Seronera            0.866
5     4  0.254     0.597   0.124  41361 Seronera            0.852
6     5  0.245     0.664   0.0832 41361 Seronera            0.909
```

And I'm trying to run a `glmer()` model as such to verify an interaction, the error associated is found below:

```
> m <- glmer(cbind(Feeding_Foraging,Standing) ~ poly(hour,2)*Area+(1|ID) , data=GLM_df , family=binomial)
Error in length(value <- as.numeric(value)) == 1L : 
  (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate
In addition: Warning message:
In eval(family$initialize, rho) : non-integer counts in a binomial glm!
```

I apologize if I'm not asking on the right forum, but does somebody know what is the cause of this error? I've been using this dataset to run other `glmer()` models not having such issue, so I hope somebody can help me.

I can provide a `dput()` sample of the data below:

```
> dput(GLM_df)
structure(list(hour = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L), Feeding = c(0.118579234700529, 
0.0919594065024507, 0.0846994533575204, 0.233092895639896, 0.254098360072561, 
0.244523639258233, 0.238513660654777, 0.245289616923379, 0.211748633393801, 
0.253514225911475, 0.275555554923133, 0.222477230819087, 0.232641165221989, 
0.238368461591879, 0.30265937999754, 0.433661201190504, 0.178745053292422, 
0.12125395428024, 0.10605844594333, 0.163238946470857, 0.174611180767811, 
0.22483854891269, 0.177868852050793, 0.183918813004901, 0.241998438164344, 
0.161698956409812, 0.158105646267371, 0.36138433432542, 0.468670308578279, 
0.333151183206247, 0.32072859671381, 0.301413227120555, 0.295571885509692, 
0.313952640445209, 0.343315117609149, 0.309435336266141, 0.345573769698683, 
0.307176684176607, 0.322987248803344, 0.303788706042306, 0.266520946564997, 
0.179710144515087, 0.151781420416677, 0.272293057460473, 0.384777516681307, 
0.358157688483229, 0.370418942683556, 0.295571885509692, 0.194038747691774, 
0.0980730512560762, 0.104719324151116, 0.287394007254483, 0.360255008280653, 
0.356867030146353, 0.303788706042306, 0.297908422154037, 0.295883423728938, 
0.309435336266141, 0.335409835295781, 0.294754097684171, 0.329763205071946, 
0.311693988355675, 0.252969034027794, 0.320554854245385, 0.269908924699298, 
0.114670029160951, 0.145400728263743, 0.208925318281884, 0.252065573191981, 
0.343637782193368, 0.234552332374672, 0.25071038193826, 0.139938227286338, 
0.127049180036281, 0.0779234970889187, 0.271038250744065, 0.37923497180722, 
0.365027321566604, 0.313661201465914, 0.342076501947147, 0.292896174191167, 
0.283060108639971, 0.271038250744065, 0.238251365573412, 0.196721311023918, 
0.191256830162143, 0.16601092858074, 0.0626775954845651, 0.134426229199678, 
0.105704917790185, 0.11195058182907, 0.140192198660723, 0.14806719253611, 
0.21262483463543, 0.226733921295516, 0.21891551021636, 0.120612021581109, 
0.140939890386914, 0.0931693986932724, 0.2142076497816, 0.228415300022216, 
0.194244079699913, 0.181821493207477, 0.186922931547631, 0.153588342088304, 
0.15187488188245, 0.135519125372033, 0.171657558804575, 0.144302772386887, 
0.113322027250751, 0.0931693986932724, 0.0657666343717217, 0.126775955993192, 
0.0912147959234835, 0.0966201171633936, 0.143219075677262, 0.127049180036281, 
0.145683059774935, 0.171657558804575, 0.140731399424803, 0.238570126957016, 
0.109339294334254, 0.14013909555517, 0.190856101565613, 0.175240248325904, 
0.217486338298665, 0.251366119641673, 0.295081966535877, 0.278688523950551, 
0.268852458399355, 0.349726775153633, 0.328961747878886, 0.351912567498343, 
0.284153004812326, 0.220218578729553, 0.179437360446302, 0.283460837236502, 
0.156693988711413, 0.114187411193102, 0.207187893597627, 0.198761383878981, 
0.22134790477432, 0.199890709923748, 0.218466176246294), Foraging = c(0.78939890529209, 
0.81876138245603, 0.824408012679865, 0.632422585069486, 0.59741347768171, 
0.66404371432296, 0.599672129771244, 0.632422585069486, 0.629034606935185, 
0.575956282831139, 0.525136610816626, 0.588378869323575, 0.577085608875906, 
0.574826956786372, 0.482222221115483, 0.336377829048438, 0.677595626860163, 
0.811985426187429, 0.797304187605459, 0.744225863501412, 0.727285972829908, 
0.702440799845036, 0.721639342606074, 0.744225863501412, 0.593480307663729, 
0.692276865442133, 0.705828777979336, 0.29136611954987, 0.178520386307389, 
0.320647930567756, 0.343470886718772, 0.422913132626516, 0.393706424572198, 
0.350480496651808, 0.350091073877751, 0.339966081752254, 0.289107467460336, 
0.294403617187519, 0.226644054501503, 0.185602280400827, 0.465282330443979, 
0.671948996636328, 0.677595626860163, 0.525136610816626, 0.359125682235886, 
0.398652093802729, 0.407725644438271, 0.496903459697453, 0.519489980592792, 
0.647103823651456, 0.618870672532282, 0.247583017506598, 0.159987856341983, 
0.170810564270999, 0.290898812221001, 0.315807961804469, 0.2952380945605, 
0.274543055710583, 0.21405861848537, 0.274947456283643, 0.241067674940635, 
0.254098360072561, 0.192437158028286, 0.1589743586095, 0.334732239668921, 
0.591766847457876, 0.587638966052866, 0.500018841889913, 0.436807180886641, 
0.401884302827407, 0.44922080447396, 0.438017173077463, 0.748633878063245, 
0.820765025438681, 0.896174861331183, 0.336612021085371, 0.116546447819948, 
0.204633879311769, 0.282720933965792, 0.313952640445209, 0.293235348865346, 
0.217959926640019, 0.244687309699503, 0.267759562227, 0.256357012162095, 
0.20666666619235, 0.110109289364776, 0.0532396563961557, 0.284590163281268, 
0.810928959887485, 0.790163932612739, 0.619999998577049, 0.523384208333367, 
0.47682655223493, 0.493009231956877, 0.637874503906291, 0.632422585069486, 
0.726775954616143, 0.817486336921616, 0.340983605774792, 0.142779078516963, 
0.193598750531475, 0.256357012162095, 0.254682494233647, 0.206783493024567, 
0.19198542761038, 0.221428570920375, 0.213793102957603, 0.203278688058049, 
0.194157208465701, 0.112932604476694, 0.0948633877604228, 0.380582877086458, 
0.787978140268028, 0.810928959887485, 0.719125681409657, 0.625136610587118, 
0.562404370293935, 0.366120217738959, 0.535519124454, 0.655009105964824, 
0.782513659406253, 0.757377047442085, 0.18996877395901, 0.158105646267371, 
0.182574377237322, 0.24367381196702, 0.248087431124608, 0.269869982421893, 
0.283586317908142, 0.23846153791425, 0.29272131080359, 0.220218578729553, 
0.13834244048395, 0.101639344029024, 0.0846994533575204, 0.23846153791425, 
0.745355189546179, 0.686338796239004, 0.605318759995079, 0.500936767000192, 
0.414375787195254, 0.393442622047837, 0.509364988467295), Standing = c(0.0338797813430082, 
0.0338797813430082, 0.0677595626860163, 0.131754705222809, 0.124225864924363, 
0.0831594632964746, 0.162622950446439, 0.101639344029024, 0.112932604476694, 
0.0931693986932724, 0.0975737702678635, 0.101639344029024, 0.12046144477514, 
0.128743169103431, 0.137059115433078, 0.14761904728025, 0.0677595626860163, 
0.0338797813430082, 0.0338797813430082, 0.0639951425367932, 0.0423497266787602, 
0.0677595626860163, 0.107285974252859, 0.054207650148813, 0.0790528231336857, 
0.0609836064174147, 0.0451730417906775, 0.195749847759603, 0.229629629102611, 
0.225865208953388, 0.198259461192418, 0.160928961379289, 0.183201780595526, 
0.203278688058049, 0.149321999252517, 0.198605614769358, 0.212958625584623, 
0.281462798849606, 0.306128024277895, 0.398379497860889, 0.111677797760286, 
0.0677595626860163, 0.0547288775540901, 0.0931693986932724, 0.145830363172079, 
0.153350589236774, 0.105403764178248, 0.149071037909236, 0.152459016043537, 
0.135519125372033, 0.119882303213721, 0.254098360072561, 0.296740153831865, 
0.255227686117328, 0.178182553729895, 0.206102003169966, 0.186338797386545, 
0.175045536938875, 0.264028640811029, 0.235903662684649, 0.235855400887864, 
0.189259468191977, 0.333151183206247, 0.403169397981797, 0.203278688058049, 
0.0884638735067435, 0.116461748366591, 0.127819175066803, 0.183918813004901, 
0.155538996165628, 0.179710144515087, 0.15951730382333, 0.190573770054421, 
0.167140254625507, 0.11067395238716, 0.392349725875482, 0.526775955075159, 
0.469945354112694, 0.421857922529069, 0.365901638504488, 0.43278688425262, 
0.506010927800412, 0.515846993351608, 0.493989069904506, 0.555191255556392, 
0.608743168001792, 0.768306009165636, 0.947540981431873, 0.590163933071755, 
0.169398906715041, 0.163752276491206, 0.297658078942143, 0.42228727459678, 
0.412398717726961, 0.432306009936784, 0.283743168747693, 0.300400727908006, 
0.183201780595526, 0.132573057429162, 0.444808742148526, 0.6426229493448, 
0.637158468483024, 0.575956282831139, 0.58688524455469, 0.657923495757771, 
0.690710380928424, 0.664480872791902, 0.633879779965959, 0.690710380928424, 
0.731147539305563, 0.828415298645167, 0.933333331191257, 0.504918031628057, 
0.161580495635885, 0.141411261257773, 0.231511839177222, 0.389617485444594, 
0.325245900892878, 0.467759561767984, 0.370341058128744, 0.244523639258233, 
0.255094824229708, 0.184927139830586, 0.643715845517155, 0.774863386199767, 
0.676502730687808, 0.544262293832841, 0.456830600044432, 0.468852457940339, 
0.48415300435331, 0.450273223010302, 0.43497267659733, 0.449180326837947, 
0.608743168001792, 0.724590162271432, 0.816393440749261, 0.525683058902804, 
0.196825396373666, 0.2766848809679, 0.298142075818472, 0.393247462017059, 
0.468475597191251, 0.426885244921903, 0.380496005852245), ID = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("41361", 
"41365", "41366", "41366bis", "41367", "41368"), class = "factor"), 
    Area = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Loliondo", 
    "Seronera"), class = "factor"), Feeding_Foraging = c(0.907978139992619, 
    0.910720788958481, 0.909107466037385, 0.865515480709382, 
    0.851511837754272, 0.908567353581193, 0.838185790426022, 
    0.877712201992865, 0.840783240328986, 0.829470508742613, 
    0.800692165739759, 0.810856100142662, 0.809726774097895, 
    0.81319541837825, 0.784881601113022, 0.770039030238942, 0.856340680152585, 
    0.933239380467668, 0.903362633548788, 0.90746480997227, 0.901897153597719, 
    0.927279348757726, 0.899508194656866, 0.928144676506314, 
    0.835478745828073, 0.853975821851945, 0.863934424246708, 
    0.65275045387529, 0.647190694885669, 0.653799113774003, 0.664199483432583, 
    0.724326359747071, 0.68927831008189, 0.664433137097017, 0.6934061914869, 
    0.649401418018395, 0.634681237159019, 0.601580301364126, 
    0.549631303304847, 0.489390986443134, 0.731803277008976, 
    0.851659141151415, 0.82937704727684, 0.797429668277099, 0.743903198917193, 
    0.756809782285958, 0.778144587121826, 0.792475345207145, 
    0.713528728284566, 0.745176874907532, 0.723589996683398, 
    0.534977024761081, 0.520242864622636, 0.527677594417352, 
    0.594687518263307, 0.613716383958506, 0.591121518289437, 
    0.583978391976724, 0.54946845378115, 0.569701553967814, 0.570830880012581, 
    0.565792348428236, 0.44540619205608, 0.479529212854885, 0.604641164368219, 
    0.706436876618826, 0.733039694316609, 0.708944160171797, 
    0.688872754078621, 0.745522085020775, 0.683773136848632, 
    0.688727555015723, 0.888572105349583, 0.947814205474962, 
    0.974098358420102, 0.607650271829437, 0.495781419627168, 
    0.569661200878373, 0.596382135431706, 0.656029142392356, 
    0.586131523056514, 0.501020035279991, 0.515725560443569, 
    0.506010927800412, 0.453078323186013, 0.397923496354493, 
    0.276120217945516, 0.115917251880721, 0.419016392480946, 
    0.916633877677671, 0.902114514441809, 0.760192197237773, 
    0.671451400869477, 0.68945138687036, 0.719743153252393, 0.856790014122652, 
    0.753034606650595, 0.867715845003057, 0.910655735614888, 
    0.555191255556392, 0.371194378539179, 0.387842830231389, 
    0.438178505369572, 0.441605425781279, 0.360371835112871, 
    0.34386030949283, 0.356947696292407, 0.385450661762178, 0.347581460444935, 
    0.307479235716452, 0.206102003169966, 0.160630022132145, 
    0.50735883307965, 0.879192936191512, 0.907549077050879, 0.862344757086919, 
    0.752185790623399, 0.70808743006887, 0.537777776543534, 0.676250523878803, 
    0.89357923292184, 0.891852953740506, 0.897516142997256, 0.380824875524623, 
    0.333345894593276, 0.400060715535987, 0.495039931608694, 
    0.543169397660485, 0.548558506372443, 0.552438776307497, 
    0.588188313067882, 0.621683058682476, 0.572131146227896, 
    0.422495445296276, 0.321857922758577, 0.264136813803823, 
    0.521922375150751, 0.902049178257592, 0.800526207432105, 
    0.812506653592706, 0.699698150879173, 0.635723691969573, 
    0.593333331971585, 0.727831164713589)), row.names = c(NA, 
-144L), vars = "hour", indices = list(c(0L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 96L, 
120L), c(1L, 25L, 49L, 73L, 97L, 121L), c(2L, 26L, 50L, 74L, 
98L, 122L), c(3L, 27L, 51L, 75L, 99L, 123L), c(4L, 28L, 52L, 
76L, 100L, 124L), c(5L, 29L, 53L, 77L, 101L, 125L), c(6L, 30L, 
54L, 78L, 102L, 126L), c(7L, 31L, 55L, 79L, 103L, 127L), c(8L, 
32L, 56L, 80L, 104L, 128L), c(9L, 33L, 57L, 81L, 105L, 129L), 
    c(10L, 34L, 58L, 82L, 106L, 130L), c(11L, 35L, 59L, 83L, 
    107L, 131L), c(12L, 36L, 60L, 84L, 108L, 132L), c(13L, 37L, 
    61L, 85L, 109L, 133L), c(14L, 38L, 62L, 86L, 110L, 134L), 
    c(15L, 39L, 63L, 87L, 111L, 135L), c(16L, 40L, 64L, 88L, 
    112L, 136L), c(17L, 41L, 65L, 89L, 113L, 137L), c(18L, 42L, 
    66L, 90L, 114L, 138L), c(19L, 43L, 67L, 91L, 115L, 139L), 
    c(20L, 44L, 68L, 92L, 116L, 140L), c(21L, 45L, 69L, 93L, 
    117L, 141L), c(22L, 46L, 70L, 94L, 118L, 142L), c(23L, 47L, 
    71L, 95L, 119L, 143L)), group_sizes = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L), biggest_group_size = 6L, labels = structure(list(
    hour = 0:23), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame", vars = "hour"), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: You should first address the warning regarding non-integer counts. It is important.

Comment: @Roland Thank you for your question. What do you suggest I should do about it?

Comment: Read the documentation regarding which input is appropriate for the binomial family.

Comment: A bit more detail could have been nice in the counter comments. There are two problems here, one is likely addressed by fixing the other. You are fitting a binomial model. The input response should either be a vector of 0 and 1's (proportions in between work as well), or a data.frame with 2 columns containing only count data. This is also the case for any other binomial model. It is Binomial, and can only take on a value of 'succes' or 'failure' (1 or 0).